# GraphQL Axios variables {} injection

Tags: graphql, axios

i am writing a simple post example to Grapql using axios.
Perfect working example

```
            let body =  { 
                query: `
                    query {
                        game(id:"5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a38") {
                            _id
                            title
                        }
                    }
                `, 
                variables: {}
            }
            axios.post("http://localhost:3344/graphql", body)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data) // cool data from server
                })
```

But i would like to use this kind of variables that i saw i some example but i can't make it work

```
            let body =  { 
                query: `
                    query {
                        game(id: $id) { // IT SUPPOSE THE ID VARIABLE SHOULD BE INJECTED HERE
                            _id
                            title
                        }
                    }
                `, 

                variables: {id: "5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a38"} // DECLARED VARIABLE ID
            }
            axios.post("http://localhost:3344/graphql", body)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data) // 400 (Bad Request)
                })
```

GRaphQl type declaration

```
            type Query {
                game(id: String!): Game!
            }
```

According to the comments i also tried this. But still not working

```
            let body =  { 
                query: `
                    query {
                        Game($id: String!) {
                            game(id: $id) {
                                _id
                                title
                            }
                        }
                    }
                `, 
                variables: {id: "5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a38"}
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your type declaration to:

```js
 type Query {
   game(id: ID!): Game!
 }
```

then:

```js
const query = `query Game($id: ID!) {
                 game(id: $id) {
                    id
                    title
                 }
              }`;

axios.post("http://localhost:3344/graphql", 
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query,
    variables: { id: "5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a38" },
  })
).then(res => {
     console.log(res.data)
})
```

Comment: but in `game(id: ID!)` the id type is an String

Comment: @roll what is the type of the `id` in your type definition ? `type Game { id: ID! ...` for example the type here is ID, if so then you need to change your query def from `game(id: String!): Game!` to `game(id: ID!): Game!` else change the query from client to ```const query = `query Game($id: String!) { ...```

Comment: Thanks, your example was the most closest to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone, I finally discovered how to fix the problem.

Maybe someone else can need it.

Type definition

```
type Query {
    game(id: String!): Game!
}
```

The query should be like this

```
let body =  { 
    query: `
        query Game($id: String!) { // notice the query Game structure
            game(id: $id) {
                _id
                title
            }
        }`, 
    variables: {id: "5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a38"}
}

axios.post("http://localhost:3938/api/v1/graphql", body)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing id variable in your query you have to define it on query level like this

```
 let body =  { 
                query: `
                    query ($id: ID) {
                        game(id: $id) { // IT SUPPOSE THE ID VARIABLE SHOULD BE INJECTED HERE
                            _id
                            title
                        }
                    }
                `, 

                variables: {id: "5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a38"} // DECLARED VARIABLE ID
            }
```

NOTE : your type must me be same with backend like ID or String

Comment: I updated the question with the type declaration. I tried your example but not working. Just with one change `query($id:String)`

Comment: can you tell me what is your id type on api ? if it's ID type then you have to write it same here.

Comment: i added the type example.

Comment: have you tried it with query ($id: String!)  because ! is necessary

Comment: query ($id: String!) works. The key is to match schema. You shouldn't have to change schema to accommodate the client.