# I am facing a difficult and critical problem with javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, graphql, react-graph-vis

I am building a React-Nextjs application. I am connecting graphql api in my project. I write one request function-

```
await axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL as string, {
    query: `
    query isListed {
        isListed(name: ["Thor: Love and Thunder"]) {
          name
          isWatchlisted
          isWishlisted
        }
      }`
})
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is working properly. Here You can see that `["Thor: Love and Thunder"]`, I am sending static data. When I try to use dynamic data Then I face the problem. The api documentation says that they only accept array of string.

Here is example when I try to use dynamic data-

```
const test = ["Thor: Love and Thunder"]
//Here I try to use this test data

await axios.post(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL as string, {
    query: `
    query isListed {
        isListed(name: ${test}) {
          name
          isWatchlisted
          isWishlisted
        }
      }`
})
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

When I try it, it gives me a syntax error. But I can't understand what is the different between this two example. Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GraphQL Axios variables {} injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55400909/graphql-axios-variables-injection)

Answer (score 0):

You are interpolating strings. Arrays, when coerced into a string, will be joined with commas, but without brackets. For instance, `` let a=[1,2,3]; let s=`${a}`; `` will give you the string s with value `'1,2,3'`.

In your case, you have two options: use a string literal instead of the array, or use `JSON.stringify` when interpolating.

So either

```
const test = '["Thor: Love and Thunder"]'
…
```

or

```
…
query: `
    query isListed {
        isListed(name: ${JSON.stringify(test)}) {
          name
          isWatchlisted
          isWishlisted
        }
      }`
…
```